# Creating an autorized, all privileged user and an identically named DB via CLI (Bash) in one row

Tags: command-line, mysql

I frequently need to do the following things in MySQL:

1. Create a non-root user
2. Set that user's password
3. Grant that user all privileges
4. Make a database with the same name as the new user
5. Allow usage only for users from the `localhost`.

Previously I did this using PHPmyadmin, but I would prefer doing it directly from BASH. Is there a CLI way to execute these steps?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it appears off topic, and is likely a better fit at https://serverfault.com or maybe at https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It’s not obvious from my parsing of your question which behavior is desired versus avoided.

Comment: I edited the question. I want to do the same thing I always did with PMA, but from the CLI --- Setting up a new DB user, a DB with the same name as of the user, the users password, and making sure the new user has all privileges. These are the 4 actions I want to do from the CLI.

Comment: I tried to explain better what I aim to do from the CLI. I hope the question is clear and valid in it's current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
echo 'create database testdb; create user "testdb"@"%" identified by "mypassword"; grant all privileges on testdb.* to testdb;' | mysql -u root -p
```

The percentage sign indicates that connections to this database may be made from other systems. Replace the `%` with `localhost` if you only need an account that needs access to and from the same system.

Comment: Thank you dearly. Why did you use echo?

Comment: Very good question. Depending on how software is written, commands can receive input from files, the keyboard, or something called stdin (standard-in). Echo outputs by default to stdout (standard-out). You can connect the two together with the pipe command (vertical bar). Rather than first creating a text file and then running the text file against the mysql command I opted to do it all in one line.

Comment: I now understand that we echo what is written before the pipe, and then use the piped output as content for mysql.

Comment: Correct. It only works for certain programs, and sometimes you may need to provide an additional argument like a dash ( - ) or so, but check the command's man page and it will tell you if and how it can read inputs.